# How to display Japanese characters in csv download in python for web scraping

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I cannot display the Japanese character on the downloaded csv file I created. How to do that? I am new to python.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

csv_file = open('details.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
csv_writer.writerow(['company Name', 'link', 'established', 'members', 'address'])

for i in range(1):
    res = requests.get('https://abcdefg.com/projects?type=mixed&page='+str(i))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
    site = soup.select('h1>a', href=True)

    for i in site:
        res = requests.get('https://abcdefg.com/projects/' + i['href'][10:16])
        soup1 = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')

        data = soup1.find('div', class_='company')
        company_name = (data.a.text).strip()

        data = soup1.find('div', class_='company-info-list')
        company_desc = data.find_all('div', class_='company-description')
        try:
            company_link = company_desc[0].text.strip()
        except Exception as e:
            company_link = "None"

        try:
            company_established = company_desc[1].text.strip()
        except Exception as identifier:
            company_established = "None"

        try:
            company_members = company_desc[2].text.strip()
        except Exception as identifier:
            company_members = "None"

        try:
            company_address = company_desc[4].text.strip()
        except Exception as identifier:
            company_address = "None"

        csv_writer.writerow([company_name, company_link, company_established, company_members, company_address])

csv_file.close()
```

I searched for solutions but this

```
csv_file = open('details.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
```

code cannot do the thing.

[image]

This is the result on the csv file. I also want to remove the rows that have no data on it. Please help. I am on windows 10

Comment: That _looks_ like UTF-8 printed as if it is Latin-1 or similar. Either the program you screenshotted doesn't read the file as UTF-8, or you read the UTF-8 data as if they were 8-bit, then re-encoded into UTF-8. Since you posted a picture for the output, and I can't find any Japanese on the URL you posted, it is quite hard to tell what exactly went wrong.

Comment: The requested characters were in Japanese from a Japanese website. After processing with that code and downloaded into csv, that weird character appeared as output.